# Failed to load method of a DLL C# from java project

Tags: java, c#, dll, native

Here is my C# code (exported in a DLL file)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DLLTest
{    
        [ComVisible(true)]
        public Boolean MethodeTest()
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my java code :

```
package mypackage.global;
public class Class1 {
    public native boolean MethodeTest();
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("DLLTest");
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Class1().MethodeTest();
    }
}
```

When I run the java code, I have this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: mypackage.global.Class1.MethodeTest()Z
    at mypackage.global.Class1.MethodeTest(Native Method)
    at mypackage.global.Class1.main(Class1.java:11)
```

DLL is in the Java Build Path.
Do you have any idea of a mistake I did ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: The mistake is that Java and C# are very different languages -- you can't simply call from one into the other like that. `System.loadLibrary` expects the library to contain native, compiled machine code. But a .NET DLL contains IL, an intermediate language which is processed by the .NET Runtime. The Java runtime doesn't know what to do with code intended for the .NET Runtime.

Comment: Ok so what do you suggest me to do ? Use a bridge like jni4net ?

Comment: First, consider whether this is something you *really* need to be doing -- it's not straightforward. JNI is one option, other IPC mechanisms like TCP are another

Comment: Yeah sure, I realy have to do it, this is a job's constraint... Thanks for your answers !